# How do I prevent removal of auth0 session cookie on refresh?

Tags: authentication, cookies, auth0, sveltekit, auth0-js

I have a simple demo app based on SvelteKit in which I am attempting to use auth0 for authentication. The initial authentication works as expected, and is executed like this (I also have a `stores.js` file where writable stores are created to hold the state of `user`, `isAutheniticated`, and `popupOpen`, and an `auth_config.js` file to hold my auth0 credentials.):

```
// authService.js
import { createAuth0Client } from "@auth0/auth0-spa-js";
import { user, isAuthenticated, popupOpen } from "./store";
import config from "../auth_config";

async function createClient() {
  let auth0Client = await createAuth0Client({
    domain: config.domain,
    clientId: config.clientId
  });
  return auth0Client;
}

async function loginWithPopup(client, options) {
  let c = await client.loginWithPopup(options);
  user.set(await client.getUser());
  isAuthenticated.set(true);
}

function logout(client) {
  return client.logout();
}
```

```
//+layout.svelte
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import auth from "../authService";
  import { isAuthenticated, user } from "../store";

  let auth0Client;

  onMount(async () => {
    auth0Client = await auth.createClient();
    isAuthenticated.set(await auth0Client.isAuthenticated());
    user.set(await auth0Client.getUser());
  });

  function login() {
    auth.loginWithPopup(auth0Client);
  }

  function logout() {
    auth.logout(auth0Client);
  }

</script>

{#if $isAuthenticated}
  <a class="nav-link" href="/#" on:click="{logout}">Log Out</a>
{:else}
  <a class="nav-link" href="/#" on:click="{login}">Log In</a>
{/if}

<slot />
```

And when I login I see a cookie named `auth0.MY_CLIENT_ID.is.authenticated` and its value is "true".

However, when I refresh the page, the cookie is removed. When I click the login link, the auth0 popup briefly displays but then closes itself and I am logged in again, and the cookie is set again.

It seems to me I am doing something wrong, since the auth0 client knows I am logged in and does not ask for my credentials again, but my app is not aware I am logged in. What is the proper way to hang on to the session cookie so that it does not appear that I am logged out when I refresh?

Answer (score 2):

Researching some more, I came across [this very helpful post](https://community.auth0.com/t/why-is-authentication-lost-after-refreshing-my-single-page-application/56276) from the auth0 message boards.

Allowing 3rd party cookies "solved" my problem, but obviously I don't want my end users to have to do that. Instead, I enabled refresh tokens within my application settings on auth0.com, and then within my client I enabled local storage and refresh tokens:

```
async function createClient() {
  let auth0Client = await createAuth0Client({
    domain: config.domain,
    clientId: config.clientId,
    cacheLocation: 'localstorage',
    useRefreshTokens: true
  });
  return auth0Client;
}
```

Now my authentication survives a refresh (even with 3rd party cookies blocked).